# Fstream giving blank lines while reading file, on use with pthreads

Tags: c++, pthreads, fstream

I am trying to implement the reader writer problem on file read/write instead of just a variable in C++. For that purpose I have declared a global `fstream` variable which opens the file. and two functions, one for reader, one for writer. Here is my code:

```
#include<pthread.h>
#include<semaphore.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

/// One writer, multiple readers


// initialize the file to be read and write 
fstream file("text.txt",ios::in|ios::out|ios::app);

// declare semaphore and mutex
sem_t rw_semaphore;
pthread_mutex_t multiread_mutex;

// variable to keep track of number of readers
int readers = 0;

void *writer(void *arg){
    // try to get the semaphore for accessing the file
    sem_wait(&rw_semaphore);
    // write to the file
    file << "Wrote to the file.."<<*(int *)arg<<endl;
    cout<<"Writer no. "<<*(int *)arg<<" wrote to the file"<<endl;
    // signal realease of semaphore for accessing the file
    sem_post(&rw_semaphore);
}

void *reader(void *arg){
    // Lock mutex for accessing readers count variable
    pthread_mutex_lock(&multiread_mutex);
    readers++;
    // if this is the first reader, try to get the semaphore
    if(readers == 1){
        sem_wait(&rw_semaphore);
    }
    // release mutex lock
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&multiread_mutex);
    // read the file
    cout<<"Reader no: "<<*(int *)arg<<" reading file: -"<<endl;
    for(string line;getline(file,line);){
        cout<<line<<endl;
    }
    file.clear();
    // lock mutex
    pthread_mutex_lock(&multiread_mutex);
    readers--;
    // if this is the last reader, release the semaphore
    if(readers == 0){
        sem_post(&rw_semaphore);
    }
    // release mutex lock
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&multiread_mutex);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t read[7], write[5];
    pthread_mutex_init(&multiread_mutex,NULL);
    sem_init(&rw_semaphore,0,1);
    int *arg = new int;
    for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
        *arg = i+1;
        pthread_create(&read[i],NULL,reader,(void *)arg);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        *arg = i+1;
        pthread_create(&write[i],NULL,writer,(void *)arg);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
        pthread_join(read[i],NULL);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
        pthread_join(write[i],NULL);
    }

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&multiread_mutex);
    sem_destroy(&rw_semaphore);
    file.close();

    return 0;
}
```

But the `cout` printing the lines in the file is not printing anything. Here is the output I get:

```
Reader no: 2 reading file: -

Reader no: 3 reading file: -

Reader no: 4 reading file: -

Reader no: 5 reading file: -

Reader no: 6 reading file: -

Reader no: 7 reading file: -

Reader no: 1 reading file: -

Writer no. 2 wrote to the file
Writer no. 3 wrote to the file
Writer no. 3 wrote to the file
```

The writer is writing to the file fine, and the file is not empty at time of reading. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unrelated: Are you programming in C++11 or later? If so, why not use the standard C++ class `std::thread` and friends instead of the platform specific C `pthread` interface?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I know that, but I am implementing in this because I am learning pthreads.

Comment: check your position in the file when you are reading.  (tellg).  You are opening it in append mode....this will do a seek to end before every write; I am not certain if it does a seek to end on opening as well.  In short, your readers should seek to the position from which they want to read, before reading.  The writes will do that automatically because you specified append.

Comment: `pthread_t write[3];` but you have a loop that does: `for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { pthread_join(write[i], NULL); }` so you have undefined behavior when accessing the array out-of-bounds.

Comment: @TedLyngmo changed that, but still same thing

Comment: Ok, there's a lot of C style programming in the code that makes it unnecessarily hard to read. You could use a RAII wrapper for the locking/unlocking etc. With a class like `struct mutex_lock_guard { mutex_lock_guard(pthread_mutex_t& mtx) : m_mtx(mtx) { pthread_mutex_lock(&m_mtx); }  ~mutex_lock_guard() { thread_mutex_unlock(&m_mtx); } private: pthread_mutex_t& m_mtx; };` you would only need to do `mutex_lock_guard lock(multiread_mutex);` at the beginning of a scope and it'd be unlocked automatically at the end of the scope.

Answer (score 0):

The synchronization of the readers is insufficient. You can not have multiple readers try to read something from the same `iostream` object concurrently.

Furthermore @Basya already hinted, you have a misconception about where you are in the file. You have only a single index in that file which you keep advancing by both reading and writing. And which also initially was positioned at the end of the file.

As you are using the file like a pipe, you should have opened it for reading and writing independently. When running this on Windows or Cygwin, you have of course to look slightly beyond STL fstream to get non-exclusive file handles below.

Your sequencing is also slightly wrong. As the output indicates, your readers got ahead of the writers. Bad use of the semaphore and mutex. You should have used the mutex to protect `file`, and the semaphore as a counter for the number of completed writes instead. Increment from writer only, wait from reader only. Of course then 2 of the readers would starve, but you would usually be having a separate stop condition for tracking that after all writers have been joined. (And to wake up the readers after the stop condition was set, you would have incremented the semaphore again from the main thread.)

Also as a general rule of thumb: Don't wait on a semaphore while you hold a mutex, that got it all backwards. It's a different thing with a condition variable, as that one has atomic operations for switching between mutex ownership and waiting for the CV, but for a semaphore it indicates that you got the usage wrong.

Comment: if I use separate ifstream and ofstream, there wouldn't be reader writer problem I think. A OS will take care of simultaneous file access. Also, readers going forward isn't problem, the file is populated in the start. I am implementing the reader priority solution of the problem. I think the file pointer starting at end as append mode maybe the problem. Also I will interchange mutex and semaphore if that is what you mean by me using them wrong

Comment: You still have a reader / writer problem even with separate streams. That specific problem is about sequencing, but always requires a separate read and write index. The problem is defined by the requirement that the reader must never be able to "get ahead" of the writer. Having multiple competing readers / writers is then no longer about sequencing only, but adds synchronization to the mix. Synchronization is still only necessary within each of the read/write groups.

Comment: there are 3 types of reader writer problems. First is reader priority, second writer and third equal priority. I am implementing first reader writer problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writers_problem

Comment: Readers preference is not applicable if you have a pipe like structure as the buffer. It's only applicable if the readers *can* operate concurrently on a shared buffer. And you still most sequence reads after writes, for all 3 sub-problems.